# ruby on rails: form_for doesn't redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

My form_for doesn't redirect to the action I specified. I really can't fid where the problem is.

my view detailedbook:

```
<!-- Comments Form -->
    <div class="well">
      <h4>Comment:</h4>
      <form class="comment-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form_for(:comments, :url => {:action => 'post_comment'}) do |f| %>
              <%= f.text_area(:content, :rows => "3", :class => "form-control new-comment") %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, :value => @comments[:book_id] %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => session[:user_id] %>
              <%= submit_tag("Send") %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

my controller:

```
def detailedbook
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comments.new
    @rating = Rates.new(:book_id => params[:id], :user_id => session[:user_id])
    @previouscomments = Comments.where(:book_id => params[:id] )
  end
def post_comment
    @comments = Comments.new(params.require(:comments).permit(:content, :book_id, :user_id))
    @comments.book_id = params[:id]
    if @comments.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'showbooks')
    else
      redirect_to(:action => 'home')
    end
  end
```

It seems like submitting doesn't even happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the logs from a submission of the form?

Comment: Can you also please add, in an edit, the **html** that is is rendered out onto the page for your form?  It's always worth examining this as it's the rendered html which determines what is submitted with the form, and often it's not what you expected to get from your erb file.

Comment: Where can I get the logs from a submission of the form?

Comment: I found a mistake when I checked page source. Thanks for the idea, I didn't think I could actually see anything there :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `url` you specified is not working correctly. Assuming `Comments` is your controller's name:

```
<%= form_for(:comments, :url => post_comment_comments_url, :method=> "POST" ) do |f| %>
```

This should work for you.

Comment: comments is not my controller's name. should it be?

Comment: what do you mean by post_comment_comment_url? Is this the action name?

Comment: In you form definition you have not specified controller's name along with action. Rails does not know where to take you when you submiit your form. Either you specify controller's name along with action or specify your target url and request method like i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: What is your controller's name btw?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a "Comments" model and what you are sharing is on the comments_controller. You shouldn't have used a plural form for your model. You should use Comment for a model (each object of this class is 1 comment) and the plural form for your controller.

**1st try the easy fix:**

```
<%= form_for(@comments, :url => {:action => 'post_comment'}) do |f| %>
```

@comments is the actual instance you are editing/creating. Rails realizes that and search for the right controller (comments_controller).

**2nd option**
It may be a problem due to how rails pluralize comments. You may check that in the code of the html rendered for the form page or bypass rails helper using:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: 'comments', action: 'post_comment', method: 'post') ... %>
```

If doesn't answer your question, please edit your post adding your Model and the html code for your form page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the corresponding `URI Pattern` which will direct it to respective Controller#Action or the controllers method that you want to call. Rails doesn't know which controller action you are talking about.
You can find it by `rake routes` and see the `Controller#Action` column and use the respective `URI Pattern`. 
It will loke something like this.

```
 Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
         root GET      /                                  home#index
       logout GET      /logout(.:format)                  session#destroy
        login GET      /login(.:format)                   session#new
```